# should I buy the SSL certificate with the same domain seller

Tags: ssl, amazon-web-services, https

I bought a domain from godaddy.

If I want to buy SSL certificate should I have to buy the SSL from godaddy ?

Or I can buy the SSL certificate from any seller then applied it to the domain that I bought from godaddy?

Will it be more complicated or conflict if I do so ?

I gonna deploy the SSL to EC2 instances of ELB.

And currently I use route53 to point to ELB

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter who you buy your certificate from, as long as it is a from a [Certificate Authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) that is recognized by your clients.

In truth the only difference between your self-signed certificate, a free certificate or one generated by a well known public Certificate Authority lies in how inherently trusted it is by your users.

So again, no, shop around for the best deal on a certificate from trusted vendors, you are in no way bound to stay with GoDaddy.

Comment: Hi @Reaces, thanks very much, so did you mean i can buy a SSL for the domain `http://sample.co` from Godaddy right ? because the SSL is too expensive on Godaddy, im worry about how the SSL vendor know the domain is owned by me

Comment: Simple validation that you're in charge of domain `example.co.uk` by SSL certificate resellers is done by sending the certificate either an specific `<admin user>@example.co.uk` e-mail address or the owner found in the Whois details of the domain.

Comment: @HBruijn I think you forgot an `@user` there.